# jQuery annoying initial delay

Tags: jquery, delay

**Brief**

I do not have any specific code to show, but a general question. Whenever i use jQuery, it always has a 1000-2000ms delay, before actually becoming active. How can i fix this?

---

**Example**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        alert('This has been delayed more than necessary.');
    }, 1000);
}
```

It takes 2000ms for it to initiate. I've been struggling with this problem for a long time, but i simply can't find an answer around the web. I have already searched both Stack Overflow and Google.

---

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the Jquery file linked using an url eg: www.googledocs.com or is it direct from your webserver?

Comment: Does your DOM take 1 second to finish loading? The document ready handler is there to handle the event that says, "ok, all elements have finished loading." You're running your code after that event fires. On top of that, you delay your alert by another 1 second with the `setTimeout`. If you remove both and simply `alert()`, does the delay go away?

Comment: @StijnBernards No it's local.
Cory: Still a delay :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think jQuery is intentionally delaying the execution of your code. You have two layers of callbacks here:

```
// here you are waiting for the HTML markup to finish being parsed
// and turned into a usable DOM (this is the "DOM-ready" event)
$(document).ready(function() {
    // This code does not run until the DOM is ready. Then, you delay
    // your alert by another 1 second by using this setInterval here
    setInterval(function(){
        // This will not happen for 1000ms after the DOM is ready
        alert('This has been delayed more than necessary.');
    }, 1000);
}
```

Even if your page was empty, you are delaying your code by a minimum of 1 second.

The rest of it may be due to having a large page, loading many scripts, large CSS files or font files. Check your browser's "Network" tab in its development tools to see the timings of your page loading.

FYI, if you structure your page the "best practice" way, it would look something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="external/reference.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- All your HTML are belong to us -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // put your code here, in a <script> tag right before the 
        // closing </body> tag
        alert('I'm ready!');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

...and it would not require the DOM-ready handler or the `setTimeout` function -- it simply would not run until the rest of the page has finished loading.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm already including the script at the bottom of the document.

But are you saying that there are no way to bypass that annoying delay? This won't be good in cases like a slideshow. Having to wait an extra second for the slideshow to initiate, isn't very good. :(

Comment: Are you actually using a `setTimeout` in your code? Why? You do understand that the callback function passed to the `setTimeout` method won't be executed for approximately the time period specified as the second parameter (milliseconds), in this case, your code will never execute *without* a 1-second delay.

Comment: I am aware, but i'm talking about an additional delay. If i set it to 2000ms, it initiates after 4000ms. So everything is x2, which i find odd. It happens no matter when or how i try.

Comment: So if you set it to a 10 second timeout, it would run after 20 seconds? That's definitely peculiar, and I would ask you to isolate further -- recreate the situation in a jsFiddle with a minimum amount of code, or start stripping out things unrelated to your slideshow to see if something else is affecting the load time.